# What are the 'parts' to a mechanical disc brake set?

Tags: brakes, parts, mechanical, disc-brake

So there are rotors, pads, brake lever, brake cable...I just want to make sure that if i buy brakes I can get all the parts and I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on how you buy the brake, so you need to check whats coming with what you're buying. Typically, you get the caliper+pads+rotor+mounting hardware and buy the brake lever (which is a V-brake lever most of the time unless its a road brake in which case its a regular short pull lever) separately along with the cables+housing. In some cases though (esp. buying brakes on eBay), people buy just the caliper+pads+mounting hardware and get rotors separately.

[This example](http://www.nashbar.com/bikes/ProductDisplay?storeId=10053&langId=-1&catalogId=10052&productId=572099&utm_source=Google_Product_Search&utm_medium=pla&utm_campaign=datafeed&cm_mmc=Google_Product_Search-_-PLA-_-Datafeed-_-Avid%20BB7%20Road%20G2%20160mm%20Disc%20Brake&CAWELAID=400006960000083068&source=googleUS&CAGPSPN=pla&catargetid=400006960000088447&cadevice=c&gclid=CjwKEAiA2JqkBRDshIOY_9eMghkSJABvNd1QSr3imSFUEZwPE-Ctq2_h3tBYx08aCN1bbo9lyALzIBoCrf3w_wcB) from Nashbar tells you the Avid BB7 Road comes with "Includes 1 post mount (74mm) caliper, 1 rotor (160mm) with bolts, sintered pads, and 74mm post mount to IS mount adapter".

The typical hardware (Avid BB7 Road with a G2 rotor) is shown below:

[image]
(from Nashbar)

To this you'd need to add a brake lever (e.g. Tektro RL340), some brake cable and brake housing in order to get a functioning brake system.

For maintenance and some description of the important parts, see this [Park tool repair guide](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/avid-reg-mechanical-disc-adjustment) as well.